# Proof: if $|a|<1$ then $a^n$ converges to $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to proof a basic statement:

**if $|a| < 1$, $a\in \mathbb{R}$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } a^n = 0$.**

On one hand, it's quite intuitive, on the other hand, I wasn't able to prove it formally.
Is this statement needs to be proved or it's some kind of convention?

Thank you.

Comment: For $|a|<1$ then multiply by $a^n$ to get $|a|^{n+1}<|a|^n$ thus the sequence is $\searrow$ and since it is bounded by $0$ it converges to a limit $\ell$. Since $|a|^{n+1}=|a|\times |a|^n$ the limit should verify $\ell=|a|\ell\iff \ell(|a|-1)=0$ but since $|a|-1\neq 0$ then $\ell=0$.

Comment: Thank you, it was really helpful!